# Login to Url and get Profile data and making more action to the site

Tags: java, android, exception, http-post

Lets say there is a website that doesn't provide an api service. However, a legitimate android app wants to provide a useful service. So first they ask the user to create an account on that website. Then once the user is logged in, they would be able to perform certain functions like "liking" a post, or commenting on stuff, right from the app. But obviously a CSRF token is used for all form submissions. So are android apps capable of grabbing this token? If not is there a way to ask a user for permission to grab it

So how to do this process in android have any one answer for this??

This is my code what i have done, but i am not able to figure out that when we make       `HttpPost` request It says that no csrf token/ Csrf token is not used properly...

```
    void sendGet() throws Exception {

    String url = "http://manch.net.in/adda/accounts/login/";
    String sessionId = "";
    String key="";
    URL obj = new URL(url);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
    String cs = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie("http://manch.net.in/adda/accounts/login/");
    DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(url));
    CookieStore cookieStore = httpclient.getCookieStore();
    List <Cookie> cookies =  cookieStore.getCookies();

    System.out.println("cookieeeee"+cookies);
    for (Cookie cookie: cookies) {
        if (cookie.getName().equals("csrftoken")) {
            CSRFTOKEN = cookie.getValue();
            System.out.println("cccc"+CSRFTOKEN);
        }
        if (cookie.getName().equals("sessionid")) {
            String session = cookie.getValue();
            System.out.println("session"+session);
        }


    }
    MunchWebViewClientDemoActivity d=new MunchWebViewClientDemoActivity();
    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " + url);
    System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();
    }

// HTTP POST request
void sendPost() throws Exception {

try {
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();  
        String postURL = "http://manch.net.in/adda/get_my_activity/";
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(postURL);
            //post.addHeader("csrftoken", CSRFTOKEN);
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", "abhishekkeshri"));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "1234"));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("csrftoken",CSRFTOKEN ));

            UrlEncodedFormEntity ent = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params,HTTP.UTF_8);
            post.setEntity(ent);
            HttpResponse responsePOST = client.execute(post);  
            HttpEntity resEntity = responsePOST.getEntity();
             System.out.println("ressss"+resEntity.toString());
            if (resEntity != null) {    
                Log.i("RESPONSE",EntityUtils.toString(resEntity));
            }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
         }
         }
```

thnks in Advance.